# use boost spirit parse int pair to vector

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, std-pair

The string content is like:

```
20 10 5 3...
```

it is a list of pair of int. How to use spirit parse it to `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`?

```
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
    boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(
        line.cbegin(),
        line.cend(),
        (
                   ???
        ),
        boost::spirit::qi::space
    );
```

Comment: What's a "spirit phase"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a simple parser expression like `*(int_ >> int_)` (see the tutorial and [these](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/operator/kleene.html) documentation [pages](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/numeric/signed_int.html)).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b85789a3d1605398)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::string line = "20 10 5 3";
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v;
    qi::phrase_parse(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), *(qi::int_ >> qi::int_), qi::space, v);

    for (auto& p : v) {
        std::cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
(20, 10)
(5, 3)
```

### Pro Tip 1: Validity

If you want to make sure there's no unwanted/unexpected input, check for remaining data:

- check the iterators after parsing

  ```
  auto f = line.cbegin(), l = line.cend();
  qi::phrase_parse(f, l, *(qi::int_ >> qi::int_), qi::space, v);

  if (f!=l)
      std::cout << "Unparsed input '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
  ```
- or simple require `qi::eoi` as part of the parser expression and check the return value:

  ```
  bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), *(qi::int_ >> qi::int_) >> qi::eoi, qi::space, v);
  ```

### Pro Tip 2: "Look ma, no hands"

Since the grammar is trivially the simplest thing that could parse into this datastructure, you can let Spirit do all the guesswork:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4749e45757618374)</kbd>**

```
qi::phrase_parse(line.begin(), line.end(), qi::auto_, qi::space, v);
```

That's, a grammar consisting of nothing but a single `qi::auto_`. Output is still:

```
(20, 10)
(5, 3)
```